# Syntax error on print statement (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax-error

I'm trying to print a dictionary however when I run doctests in CMD, it throws a syntax error and I cannot for the life of me see why.
Here is my code:

```
d = {}
with open(filename) as ins:
    for row in csv.reader(ins):
        d.update({row :(int(row[1]) + int(row[2]) + int(row[3]))}
        print(d)
```

According to CMD the error is at the 't'

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Which `t`? There are 6 in your piece of code.

Comment: You haven't closed the update brace, d.update({row :(int(row[1]) + int(row[2]) + int(row[3]))})

Comment: Sorry, the t in print

Comment: Thanks Alfie, completely missed that

Comment: In Python, whenever you get an incomprehensible syntax error on a line that's obviously perfectly fine, look at the line above it, and see if you're missing a `)]}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {}
with open(filename) as ins:
    for row in csv.reader(ins):
        d.update({row :(int(row[1]) + int(row[2]) + int(row[3]))})
        print(d)
```

Fix : The closing parenthesis of d.update() was missing

Comment: You could mark it as an answer then

Comment: Have to wait one minute